# Sort mix of upper & lower case string column - React-Admin

Tags: react-admin

Need to sort a column in the datagrid, which contains list of strings that start with upper & lower characters (Mix of lower & upper case).

React-Admin either sort with all upper or lower case character, but it doesn't uniformly sorts all type of cases in a column.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-admin passes the name of the column the end user wants to sort with, so it's the responsibility of the dataProvider (and, in your case, the API) to deal with uppercase / lowercase issues.

The problem isn't on the react-admin side, but on your API side.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  We will try with DataProvider/ API.  If you have some sample code snippet it might be of help to my team.

Comment: There is another issue again around sorting ReferenceArrayFields in the DataGrid.  For this too, we will give a try to fix it through DataProvider/ API as suggested.  If you think otherwise do let me know.